# Keep ratio of OneDrive thumbnail in a square frame

Tags: css, thumbnails, onedrive

in our application we are displaying a list of shared files in OneDrive. If they are image files, we show a thumbnail in a 40x40 square img. We get the thumbnail preview as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659743.aspx#display_a_preview_of_a_onedrive_item

This works perfectly, however, I would like when I get the preview to resize it keeping its original ratio (with max hight 40px and width 40px). Now the thumbnail becomes always 40x40 which is not a problem if it was originally say 60x60. However, when it is 96x72, it is displayed to fit 40x40. My css looks like this:

```
.image {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.image img {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBE8;
}
```

I do believe there should be something I can do with css so that the thumbnail is resized keeping its original ratio. It would be of great help if anybody can help with this one.

Thanks!
Stanislav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some clicking and reading around, I got the classes right. Check them out down:

```
.image img {
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   /* The last two properties center the picture in the middle of the box */
   display: inline;
   float: none;
}

.image {
   float: left;
   margin-left: 0px;
   line-height: 40px;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   border: 1px solid #EBEBE8;
   /* Down here the frame where the thumbnail will be placed is set */
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to declare width and height in a picture as the height adapts itself automatically depending on the ratio of the picture.

I would recommend taking height out of `.image` and wrapping another div element around the thumbnail which has the property `overflow:hidden` so that the thumbnail is in the original ratio, while still fitting in the Square.

Comment: Unfortunately this was they become max 40px wide, but the hight is sometimes more thus keeping the original ratio